# Postgresql FTS solution for existing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-postgresql, postgresql-performance

In rails app, I am trying and tinkering to add fts in postgres for existing data.
Here is what I have done:

```
class AddNameFtsIndexToCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up

    execute(<<-'eosql'.strip)
      DROP INDEX IF EXISTS index_companies_name;
      CREATE INDEX index_companies_name
      ON companies
      USING gin( (to_tsvector('english', "companies"."name")) );
    eosql

    execute(<<-'eosql'.strip)
      ALTER TABLE companies ADD COLUMN name_tsv tsvector;

      CREATE TRIGGER tsv_name_update
      BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON companies FOR EACH ROW
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger(name_tsv, 'pg_catalog.english', name);

      CREATE INDEX index_companies_fts_name ON companies USING GIN (name_tsv);
    eosql
  end

  def down
    execute(<<-'eosql'.strip)
      DROP INDEX IF EXISTS index_companies_name
    eosql

    execute(<<-'eosql'.strip)
      DROP INDEX IF EXISTS index_fts_name;
      DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tsv_name_update ON companies;
      ALTER TABLE companies DROP COLUMN name_tsv
    eosql
  end
end
```

The value for name_tsv column is still empty. 
But  for just quick test , I tried this:

```
input_data = "foo"
Company.where(["to_tsvector(companies.name) @@ plainto_tsquery(?)", input_data ])
```

and compare it with this:

```
input_data = "foo"
Company.where(["companies.name ilike ? ", "%#{input_data}%"])
```

And the former is slower.

Questions:

1. Why is it slower?

2. What is the best practice to populate tsvector column for existing data?

Although my question is related to rails app, but generally it's more about postgresql fts, 
so any postgres-specific solution is still welcomed.

Comment: Please get the raw SQL that Rails runs from the Rails log, or from the PostgreSQL log after setting `log_statement = 'all'`. Then run it with `explain analyze` to get timings and plans. Paste the results into code-indented blocks in your question and if possible also paste links to copies of the plans on http://explain.depesz.com/ (a useful plan visualiser tool). See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info .\

Comment: Also - are you really trying to do a full-text-search on company names? If so, what are you trying to achieve - example queries and results where you think it's going to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it slower?

I am willing to bet it is doing a sequential scan in both cases and the tsvector conversion is slower than the pattern matching.

> What is the best practice to populate tsvector column for existing data?

You need to create indexes that PostgreSQL can use for operations such as overlapping elements.  Btree indexes (the default) don't give you that.  You need a GIN or GIST index (the big difference in this case is that there is a read/write performance tradeoff in that choice).  Also PostgreSQL won't know that it can use an index in your case because you aren't querying on the indexed column.  What you need instead is a functional index.  So you need to do something like:

```
CREATE INDEX company_name_idx_fts ON companies USING GIN (to_tsvector(name, 'English'));
```

Then you can scan the output of that function against your full text search in your query.